# Soap UI - Multiple Responses to single request

Tags: soapui

I’m wondering if someone can help with the below query.

I’m using SOAP UI to send a request to an application. The application first responds with a successful acknowledgement back to SOAP UI (this bit works fine). The application then responds a second time with the full responsey.

Is it possible to intercept the second response in SOAP UI?

I have tried creating a Mock Response to intercept the second response, however it doesn’t seem to  ever ‘receive’ the second response (I have set the mock response to listen on the port and path to which the second message is delivered).

Could someone please advise if what I am trying to do is possible? I’m not sure if I am confusing what the Mock Response is able to do.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't expect the behaviour you are describing. It sounds like you are working with an asynchronous webservice, which is usually something like a oneway service, where you hand ind a request, and merely is responded with a HTTP 200 OK response with no content. That request is then put on a queue for later processing. Once that processing is done, the asynchronous response is sent as a request on a different endpoint. Is that what you are trying to describe?

Comment: Hi Steen - yes that is exactly the issue. The second response is sent to the same end point but validated against a seperate WSDL

Comment: Same endpoint...? Thats usually not the case, but it could be true. But probably not the same serviceoperation?

Comment: Is this test done in an integrated environment with multiple users, or is it acceptable to reconfigure the environment, to make use of some stubs/mocks?